# TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor. when trying to play audio

Tags: actionscript-3

I am working in Adobe Animate CC 2019, ActionScript 3.

In my main timeline, I'm using movie clips on individual frame with the `stop();` action applied on each. My main content is inside each movie clip. In each movie clip, I have a PNG sequene on one layer and another layer for the audio that I want to play. I have all the required audio in my library. Each audio has been exported for ActionScript and assigned a class. In all the movie clips, I'm playing a sound at the required frame by using a code at the desired frame on the (blank) Audio layer. An example code is:

```
var fl_SC:SoundChannel;

var s:Sound = new (b);
fl_SC = s.play();
```

where b is the class of the audio.

I have repeated all of this to create another movie clip. I create a movie clip, placed it on a frame in the main timeline, added the `stop();` action to that frame, went inside the movie clip, imported an image sequence on a layer, created another (blank) layer, added a keyframe to it, added action to the keyframe:

```
var fl_SC:SoundChannel;

var s:Sound = new (z);
fl_SC = s.play();
```

where z is the class of the audio.

The problem is, my SWF file is working fine without the audio layer, but, as soon as I add the layer with the code mentioned above, my output window throws this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
at Audi_fla::MarketShareTrend_9/frame1()
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
at Audi_fla::MainTimeline/fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_7()
```

where Audi.fla is the name of my Animate file, frame1 (inside the movie clip) is the one on which I'm trying to add this action, Market Share Trend is the name of the movie clip.

I don't know why it's mentioning the `fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_7()` part. That's the part of code in action on some other movie clip I have added on the previous frame in the main timeline.

This is the code:

```
stop();

movieClip_6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_7);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_7(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(54);
}
```

How can I get rid of the error and keep the audio playing in the required movie clip?

Comment: Why braces around class name instead of right after that class name? The proper way is: `var s:Sound = new b();` if that `b` is the class name for a sound in Animate.

Comment: That's a good meaningful lesson for you to give your classes proper meaningful mnemonic names. The **z** is a valid **DisplayObject**'s property typed **Number**, hence, error: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#z

Comment: @Vesper Actually, not so. It is not improper. As long as the result of the expression is a valid constructor, you **can** go with **new (MovieClip);**. Also you can omit **()** brackets with the **new** operator as long, as there are no mandatory arguments. However, **var anAudio:Sound = new SoundOfZ;** notation looks much more canonical and readable, this is what I agree with.

Comment: @Vesper, you might be correct. I can't say anything about it because I don't know a lot of ActionScript. Also, there are chances that Animate likes the class name inside the braces as that's how I have always been using it. Also, the default code snippet provided by Animate has it like that. I don't know why the difference then.

Comment: @Organis You got it totally on point. Changed the class name and it was fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Organis in the comments, the problem was the class name `z`. Changed the name and the same thing now works.